# Physics Applications of Fredholm Theory:

Tags: mathematical-physics, operators

I find [Fredholm theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredholm_theory) beautiful, especially the [Liouville-Neumann series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville-Neumann_series) for solving [Fredholm integral equations of the second kind.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredholm_integral_equation) There seems to be a consensus that these equations are quite useful for physicists, but all I have read is "these are useful in physics but we don't have time for that here . . . blah, blah, blah compact operators blah blah blah existence and uniqueness blah blah blah Banach spaces blah blah blah". (I love all these topics, but the point stands.)

So my question is: Is there a simple problem in physics, perhaps suitable for advanced undergraduates, that contorts itself into a Fredholm integral equation? I reject the Poisson equation as an example, because it is too simple and there is no reason to learn Fredholm theory to solve it.

Comment: I also find the theory very beautiful, but I know very few physicists who leverage it. Of all the physicists in my department I know of only 1 group that regularly uses Fredholm theory. I'm currently using it for a project, but neither the problem nor the result are simple.

Comment: Although not a simple example, [Fredholm's Alternative Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredholm_alternative) is used to derive an adjoint equation to the linear stability equations used in fluid dynamics. The adjoint and direct equations can then be used to [decompose](http://pof.aip.org/resource/1/phfle6/v15/i9/p2525_s1) a flow field into the constituent modes of the linear stability equations.

Comment: upvoted for " blah, blah, blah compact operators blah blah blah existence and uniqueness blah blah blah Banach spaces blah blah blah". You have mastered the language of the mathematicians, Nick ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Surely. Lets consider scattering of a 1-D particle on a small potential barrier. To solve the problem, we will find energy eigenstates:
$$
H|\psi\rangle=E|\psi\rangle
$$
Set $H=p^2/2m+\epsilon U=H_0+\epsilon U$, where $\epsilon$ is a small parameter. Consider the equation
$$
(H_0-E)|\psi\rangle=|\phi\rangle
$$
Let us write a solution as
$$
|\psi\rangle=|\psi_0\rangle +G_0(E)|\phi\rangle
$$
where $|\psi_0\rangle$ lies in $E$-eigenspace of $H_0$ and $G_0(E)$ is the operator with kernel (in coordinate rep) being the casual Green function of $H_0-E$.

Now we write the original problem:
$$(H_0-E)|\psi\rangle=\epsilon U|\psi\rangle$$
so
$$
|\psi\rangle=|\psi_0\rangle +\epsilon G_0(E)U|\psi\rangle
$$
We want this to reduce to a free particle moving from left to right for $\epsilon=0$, so we write in the coordinate representation $|\psi_0\rangle=\exp(ip_Ex),\,p_E^2/2m=E,p_E>0$, and the equation:
$$
\psi(x)=\exp(ip_Ex)+\epsilon\int_{-\infty}^x G_0(E,x-x')U(x')\psi(x')dx'
$$
This is just what you want, with $K(x,y)=G_0(E,x-y)U(y),\lambda=\epsilon$, it is a Volterra second kind integral equation, and partial sums of Liouville-Neuman series give a perturbative solution to 1-D scattering.